# My php/mysql script is not working when trying to login

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do i get my login script to work i check the script i don't see any thing wrong with it can some help me out to solve or point out my errors

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("could not connect to server");
 mysql_select_db("users",$conn) or die("could not connect to database");
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['save'])){
ob_start();
$UserName = clean($_POST['UserName']);
$Password =(md5($_POST['Password']));

    $qry="SELECT FROM userstable WHERE UserName='$UserName' AND Password='$Password' AND status=1";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);

if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
            session_write_close();
            header("location: home.php");
        }else {header("location: login.php"); exit(); }
    }else { die("Query failed");}
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the error? and now stop using mysql..use mysqli. and using md5 function incorrectly.

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL-injection

Comment: you code it correctly? what is the error? and what are you expecting to happen? if there is no error, what is happening

Comment: $qry="SELECT * FROM ....";

Comment: Select at least one column and check for single quote

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing this "*" in your sql statement But to be more secure you have to fix the column you want to select within your statement

```
$qry="SELECT UserName, Password FROM userstable WHERE UserName='$UserName' AND Password='$Password' AND status=1";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);
```

But please stop using deprecated mysql_* API. use mysqli_* or PDO

You can use this

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['save'])){
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) && $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']!=''){header("Location:home.php");}
$dbh=new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;hostdbhost', 'dbusername', 'dbpassword');/*Change The Credentials to connect to database.*/
$username=$_POST['username'];
 $password =(md5($_POST['pass']));  /*Encrpt your password with md5.*/
if(isset($_POST) && $username!='' && $password!=''){
 $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT id,password,username FROM tablename WHERE username=?");
 $sql->execute(array($username));
 while($r=$sql->fetch()){
  $p=$r['password'];
  $u=$r['username'];
 }

 if($p==$password){
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']=$id;
            $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] = $u;

  header("Location:home");
 }else{
  header("Location: login.php?error=1");
 } }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss the columns which you want to select:

```
SELECT col1, col2 , ... FROM userstable WHERE UserName='$UserName' AND Password='$Password' AND status=1";
```

**Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL-injection.

Also check for Errors after executing SQL function

Comment: That's a very useful info you just rolled back

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Than add it as comment to the question and not Change my answer

Comment: I did not change your answer, I improved it, there's a functionality here to improve answers.. at  the end this a community network.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile The answer edit functionality exists to make cosmetic changes like correcting spelling and grammar, adding links, and fixing formatting. It should not be used to add new (or otherwise substantially alter) an author's content -- please note the instructions on the edit page for reference. If you have new information that you'd like to add, either add your own answer or make a comment on an existing answer.

Comment: @AlexHowansky [To include additional information only found in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)  I'm sure that you know comments don't stay forever

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Your edit does not qualify as "information only found in comments" as it's not in a comment. I'm not sure what you mean by "comments don't stay forever" --  they're subject to moderation just like posts are but they don't age out.

Answer (score 1):

Select at least one column of the selected table.

```
SELECT col1, col2 , ... 
FROM userstable 
WHERE UserName='$UserName' AND Password='$Password' AND status=1";
```

And Also Correct Your `md5` function.

change this

```
$Password =(md5($_POST['Password']));
```

to

`$Password =md5($_POST['Password']);`